# Run a .sql file present in the solution

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database, c#-4.0

I have a .sql file in my solution. This .sql file has some scripts to create database and with the help of this .sql file, I want to create a database on runtime. I got many snippets to run a .sql file in C#. But what if they are present in my own solution and solution can be placed in any location. Yes, I can get the path of file through solution path and and then execute it, but [read somewhere that it is advisable](http://www.thetechrepo.com/main-articles/504). So is this the approach I have to follow? Will it be fine if I do this even if I am publishing my application?

Answer (score 1):

You should set it to compile as an embedded resource, then call `typeof(SomeType).Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("YourNamespace.FileName.sql")`

Comment: ok...and whats that SomeType in your query? And I am not able to find my file name in NamespaceName.FileName.sql

Comment: @rapsalands: Any type in the assembly.  What?

Comment: I am not sure what should be the type in my example. Ca u help with an example or a related link? please

Answer (score 0):

Put all the sql scripts name in SchemaScripts.sql. This file will have entries like below:

```
:r .\Tables\MyTable.sql
:r .\StoredProcedures\My_SP.sql
```

Write down the following code in batch file and save it at same location of SchemaScripts.sql file:

```
sqlcmd -b -E -S .\SQLEXPRESS -d DatabaseName -i .\SchemaScripts.sql
```

Execute the batch file.